# All integer solutions of $\left(x^2+y^2-13^2\right)^4 =z^2 -2z$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can anybody help me find all integer solutions of the equation in the title? I have learnt that this kind of equation is solved by writing it in the form $x^4+y^4=z^2,$ but I can´t see how to use it here...

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x^2+y^2-13^2)^4=z^2-2z$$
so we add one to both sides:
$$(x^2+y^2-13^2)^4+1^4=(z-1)^2$$

But we know that $a^4+b^4=c^2$ has only the trivial solution $(0,0,0)$ (attributed to Fermat by infinite descent, I believe) <s>and thus your original equation has no integer solutions.</s>

**Edit** Thanks to Mark Bennet for pointing out that I can't read; it also has the trivial solutions $(a,0,a^2)$ and $(0,a,a^2)$. The former is obviously impossible, and the latter gives $a=\pm1$ so $z=0$ or $2$, $x^2+y^2=13^2$ which is a pythagorean triple! Thus $x,y=\pm5,\pm12$ in some order.

**Edit 2** as Thomas Andres pointed out in the comments, Fermat's result isn't actually needed to prove that $a^4+1=b^2$ has only trivial solutions.

Comment: ack whoops i misread the theorem didn't I, thanks for the correction :) really appreciate it

Comment: You don't need Fermat to show that $a^2+1=b^2$ has no other solutions other than $a=0.$ $b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)=1$ means that either $b-a=-1,b+a=-1,$ or $b-a=1,b+a=1.$ In either case, $a=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yup, I agree fully, but OP did specifically mention it. I might just edit that in as an aside